# the onclick method is giving me an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null error

Tags: javascript, onclick

need help why is it throwing me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Here is the code:

```
 var age = document.getElementById( "number".value);
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = function()
  {
   if (age > 1 && age <=13)
  {
  alert('you are a child'); 
  } 
  else if (age >13 && age <=19)
  {
  alert('you are a teenager')
  }
  else if (age >20 && age <=65)
  {
  alert ('you are a young adult but still considered YOUNG :D');
  }
  else if (age >65 && age <=80)
  {
  alert( 'you are  a DOM (Dirty Old Man) hahaha'); 
  }
  else if (age >80 && age <=95)
  {
  alert('you're a pensioner');
  }
  else if (age >117 && age <=999)
  {
  alert('you are DEADZZZ');
  }
  };
```

Comment: Also, your `'you're a pensioner'` will throw a syntax error. Use double quotes or escape your apostrophe.

Comment: `"number".value` ... string's do not have a `value` property, did you mean `getElementById("number").value`? It seems you have a few other syntax errors as well

Comment: My guess is that you either don't have an element with an id of "button" in your  HTML, or if you do your script tag is in the page before it

Comment: okay thanks pointing it out :D

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` will return `null` if there is no element found with that ID.